# In how many ways can we distribute $12$ candies to four kids if two of the kids are twins who must receive the same number of candies?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways can we distribute $12$ pieces of candy to $4$ kids, if two of the kids are twins and must receive an equal number of candies?

I was trying to solve this problem in AoPS, but I'm not sure if my answer is correct. The way I approached it is by choosing first how many candies to give to a the twin pair, then dividing the remaining candies to the other two kids. For example, if we gave $4$ candies to both twins, we need to distribute $4$ candies to the remaining $2$ kids which can be done $5C1$ ways. Since the twins can receive $0,1,2,3,4,5$ or $6$ candies each, I summed up the cases and got $49$. Have I got this correct?

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: 49 is the correct answer I believe, yes. Basically, you fix the number of candies you give to the twins and then you distribute the rest to the other kids. For 0 candies, there are 12 remaining so 13 ways to distribute them to the kids. For 1 candy each, 11 ways etc. Summing all this up to only one way (at 6 candies each) gives you 49 :)

Comment: Thanks @seboll13!

Comment: Consider twin kids as one group, total number of ways to distribute candies to one group and two other kids is $91$. Number of ways where the group of twin kids got assigned odd number of candies 
$ = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10 + 12 = 2 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = 6 \cdot 7 = 42~$. But as both kids in the group must have equal number of candies, they cannot have odd number of candies as a group. That leads to $91 - 42 = 49$ solutions.